# how to know if TaskTracker is running through Java code?

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to check if task tracker is running on server. How can I check using Java code?

I dont need command line solutions. Is there any Java API to check status of tasktracker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to call the service's HTTP endpoint for the JMX metrics JSON dump URL.  You can use any HTTP client library in your language of choice to do this.  You mentioned TaskTracker, so it sounds like you are running Hadoop 1.  Here is the configuration property that specifies the HTTP endpoint:

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.task.tracker.http.address</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0:50060</value>
  <description>
    The task tracker http server address and port.
    If the port is 0 then the server will start on a free port.
  </description>
</property>
```

Assuming you haven't overridden this, the URL to call with a GET request would be `http://<host>:50060/jmx`.

Many Hadoop daemons expose an HTTP server and respond to the `/jmx` URL.  This solution is not limited to just the TaskTracker.  The specific metrics payload in the JSON response will be different per daemon, but if you're just interested in whether or not the daemon is running, then simply checking for a successful HTTP response would be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Just one more question: If I receive `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ` means the TaskTracker was shutdown successfully?

Comment: @SavanPatel , a TCP connection refused could mean either 1) the process is no longer running or 2) the process has just started, but there is a brief window where it has not bound the listening socket for the HTTP server.  In practice, that window of time is brief, so this distinction isn't significant for things like monitoring dashboards.  I figured I'd mention it for completeness though.

Comment: @SavanPatel , was this helpful?  If so, then please consider accepting the answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: yes. That was helpful. I am trying to upvote the answer. But stackoverflow says I need to have min 15 credit score. I'll upvote this once I have that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SavanPatel, thanks for the response.  You can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark.  You'll also get +2 points for yourself by doing that, so you'll get closer to being able to upvote and other features.